# How do I get indices around certain values in an array

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

So I came accros this tiny but tricky problem.

I have an array of indices of error_images, something like this:

```
error_frames = [15,27,34,204,205]
```

Now I am using a for loop to iterate over these frames and add 10 frames in prior and after the erroneous frames in order to get a sequence, so that in the end, the array is more populated. I also removed duplicates (excuse MATLAB writing):

```
error_sequence = [5:44,194:215]
```

Now the tricky part:
In Order to show the sequence, I load every image and show it for a certain time using OpenCV `cv2.imshow`. When actually encountering an error, I want to increase the pause between shown images ('slow motion') and have a special overlay. This looks like this, where `frames` is a collection of my pictures of the scene:

```
for x in error_sequence:
    if x in error_frames:
        cv2.imshow('Sequence', frames[x])
        cv2.putText(frames[x], "Error!", (50, 50),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, (0, 0, 255), 3)
        cv2.waitKey(100)
    else:
        cv2.imshow('Sequence', frames[x])
        cv2.waitKey(50)
```

The problem is, that this "one-frame" overlay is way too fast and I want to slow down more frames, lets say 3 before and after the encountered error.

Is there some kind of function, that lets me do that? Something like:

```
if x+-3 in error_frames:
    ...
```

Thank you for your help and sorry, if this is an easy question, I don't know how else to describe it. And yes, I could come up with an extra array that I set to 0 if it is further away from an error frame than 3 and use a seperate if case, but I don't find that very attractive and was wondering if there is a built in function or a nice "one-liner" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
error_frames_set = set(error_frames)
delta = 3

for x in error_sequence:
    slow_frames = set(x + offset for offset in range(-delta, delta+1))
    if slow_frames.intersection(error_frames_set):
        cv2.imshow('Sequence', frames[x])
        cv2.putText(frames[x], "Error!", (50, 50),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, (0, 0, 255), 3)
        cv2.waitKey(100)
    else:
        cv2.imshow('Sequence', frames[x])
        cv2.waitKey(50)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like so maybe:

```
if any(y in error_frames for y in xrange(x-3, x+4)):
    ...
```

You can consider creating a `set` out of your `error_frames` to improve the time complexity of the contains-check:

```
error_frame_set = set(error_frames)
```

And then use this `set` in all the checks.

Comment: There is one `)` missing. I tried tmarice answer and that one solved everything. But thank you for your quick reply!

Comment: Updated it. @tmarice's answer is fine, of course. The set cast in the loop however does more harm to the performance because the intersection is `O(N)`. The `any(generator)` produces elements lazily and stops when it finds the first, hence it should be more performant, especially if there are more than 7 elements ;-)